# Button Style problems

Tags: wpf, templates, button, background, styles

I'm trying to change the style of this button but I have a problem. Before adding this code to my solution, when I put the mouse over the button, the background changed not to my style but to the default color. I look for information and I found this Setter Template. With this, I've got to remove that default background but now, when I put over the mouse, the background simply disappears. I guess it's getting its parent's background (Window), but I don't know how to use its own background, as I write in the Style code. It seems that StackOverFlow doesn't allow me to paste the entire code but I think you can understand it.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ContentPresenter
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Try adding a border before your `ContentPresenter`  and see if it works :

`<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
          <ContentPresenter ....../>
 </Border>`

Answer (score 0):

Please move your style triggers to ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    your triggers here
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: You mean this? I've modified my code. If that's the case, is not working at all.